# jquery post form from dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i have a js function which gets html to create new employee from controller, inserts it inside a form tag (for later .serialize()), and then inserts this html to createDialog div and shows this div as dialog.

```
<div id="createDialog" style="display:none;">
</div>

$.get('/Employee/Create',
     function (html) {
        html = "<form id='createEmp'>" + html;
        html = html + "</form>";
        $("#createDialog").html(html);
        $("#createDialog").dialog({
            modal: true,
            width: 500,
            buttons: { "Save": function () { postEmployee(); } },
            close: function (ev, ui) { $(this).dialog('destroy'); }
        });
     });


    function postEmployee() {

        $.post('/Employee/Create',
        $("#createEmp").serialize(),
        function (html) {
            $('#reply').html(html);
        });
    }
```

this works, but only once. with every next post all form fields from previous posts are also added to current post.
can this be fixed ?

Tahnk You !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to remove the `<form>` element you created, like this:

```
close: function (ev, ui) { $(this).dialog('destroy').empty(); }
```

You can also make the whole function a bit cleaner with [`.wrapInner()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) like this:

```
$.get('/Employee/Create', function (html) {
  $("#createDialog").html(html).wrapInner("<form id='createEmp'> />");
  $("#createDialog").dialog({
      modal: true,
      width: 500,
      buttons: { "Save": postEmployee },
      close: function (ev, ui) { $(this).dialog('destroy').empty(); }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to not create and destroy but to create and then open and close.

html

```
<div id="createDialog" style="display:none;">
</div>
```

js

```
var $dialog = $("#createDialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 500,
    buttons: { "Save": function () { postEmployee(); } },
    close: function (ev, ui) { $(this).dialog('close'); }
});
$.get('/Employee/Create', function (html) {
    html = "<form id='createEmp'>" + html;
    html = html + "</form>";
    $("#createDialog").html(html);
    $dialog.dialog("open");
});


function postEmployee() {
    $.post('/Employee/Create',
    $("#createEmp").serialize(),
    function (html) {
        $('#reply').html(html);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get('/Employee/Create',
 function (html) {
    var nodeContent= "<form id='createEmp'>" + html + "</form>";
    $("#createDialog").empty();
    $("#createDialog").html(nodeContent);
    $("#createDialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        width: 500,
        buttons: { "Save": function () { postEmployee(); } },
        close: function (ev, ui) { $(this).dialog('destroy'); }
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the excellent jquery form plugin from malsup: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Call clearForm() on success:

```
function postEmployee()
    $('#createEmp').ajaxSubmit({
        url: '/Employee/Create'
        , success: function(html){
            $('#reply').html(html);
            $('#createEmp').clearForm();
        }
    });
}
```

Call resetForm() after creating the form to prevent the browser from restoring cached values.

```
$('#createEmp').resetForm();
```